# Could not load file or assembly at startup of NETCore Web app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm having a problem with an application developed with `NetCore 2.2`,
when I deploy the app after using the publish from VS2017 with these settings: 
 - Release
 - netcoreapp2.2
 - Framework-Dependant
 - win-x64
to a IIS server, when the app try to start it says:

```
Application startup exception
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Jump.Shared.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Impossible to find specified file.
File name: 'Jump.Shared.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Now the problem seems like my referencing structure..
I have the main Project which is `Scan.Web` which is referencing `Scan.Core` and `Scan.Infrastructure` and here is the .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Scan.Core\Scan.Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Scan.Infrastructure\Scan.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then `Scan.Infrastructure` is referencing the problematic `Jump.Shared.Infrastructure` and here is the csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\JumpShared\Jump.Shared.Infrastructure\Jump.Shared.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Scan.Core\Scan.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And in the end the .csproj of the culprit:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Jump.Shared.Core\Jump.Shared.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm not able to figure why, when in Debug from VS2017 everything works fine, when publishing it on IIS, it's not able to find this reference..
The build is giving me the `Jump.Shared.Infrastructure.dll`

Comment: Check on compiled machine the date of the executable in the debug and publish folders.  Then check which version got installed on IIS.  It looks like the latest version of you code may not of been what was published.

Comment: It seems the DLL is not present in the published folder.    if it is present then version does not seem to be matching.

Comment: In the end the problem was that the pdb, for some reasons, was not the correct one, but the old one. Deleting the destination folder for the publish solved the problem